# Multiple Record Lines

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, module

I want to add multiple records in the registration screen. For example, when adding a price menu, there are columns such as "price","menu name","menu description". I want to design a multi-product page and have the user enter more than one record on the same page. I know how to do this while saving it to the database. I am a Net Core expert. But on the razor page side, that is, on the html side, I don't know how to design it. For this, if there is a javascript module or library that will make my job easier, could you please share it with me? What I need is an html page with multiple data entries.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide related code about what you have done  and what you want to achieve, It's hard to get  help you with just an idea.